# Excel Pivot Table - Display Year and Month Separately

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I'm wondering how I can create a pivot table so that the Year is populated on each row (vs. collapsed).

Below is what I want to get. I have Year on each row and there isn't an empty row when I collapsed the Year.

[image]

This is what I'm currently have. As can be seen, there is an aggregated row for each Year.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in a single column:

For the Report Layout, select to

- Show in tabular form
- Repeat all item labels
- no subtotals

**original data**

[image]

**uncollapsed**

[image]

**Collapsed**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, if year and month are **different** columns in your data, then I don't see a problem. No subtotals, no grand totals, design in tabular form, repeat all labels.

Here is picture when year is collapsed. Is this not what you want to see?

[image]

Comment: Thank you! In fact the date is in single column